# How to change the hover background color of a table row that has a specific class in bootstrap?

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

Edited:

This is the table and CSS:

```css
.table-hover tbody tr:hover {
  background-color: #fff !important;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <table class="table table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Type</th>
          <th scope="col">Column heading</th>
          <th scope="col">Column heading</th>
          <th scope="col">Column heading</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">Default</th>
          <td>Column content</td>
          <td>Column content</td>
          <td>Column content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table-primary">
          <th scope="row">Primary</th>
          <td>Column content</td>
          <td>Column content</td>
          <td>Column content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table-dark">
          <th scope="row">Primary</th>
          <td>Column content</td>
          <td>Column content</td>
          <td>Column content</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

The row that doesn't have a class gets the background color but the row with "table-primary" remains the same. I tried a few combinations and none of them worked.

```css
.table {
  &.table-primary:hover,
  &.table-primary tr:hover {
    background-color: #fff !important;
  }
}
```

How can I get this to work?

[Stack Blitz](https://web-platform-dlzke5.stackblitz.io)

Comment: You had improperly referenced the CSS cdn, updated for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is actually doing the hover - just not using the color you tried to apply due to the `.table-hover`  and specificity due to https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/content/tables/#how-do-the-variants-and-accented-tables-work

To use your own hover on all rows you can remove the `table-hover` class and force it on the `td`.

```css
table.table>tbody>tr:hover td,
table.table>tbody>tr:hover th {
  background-color: #ff4444 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Type</th>
      <th scope="col">Column heading</th>
      <th scope="col">Column heading</th>
      <th scope="col">Column heading</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Default</th>
      <td>Column content</td>
      <td>Column content</td>
      <td>Column content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="table-primary">
      <th scope="row">Primary</th>
      <td>Column content</td>
      <td>Column content</td>
      <td>Column content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="table-dark">
      <th scope="row">Primary</th>
      <td>Column content</td>
      <td>Column content</td>
      <td>Column content</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div>
  Fix for When either .table-striped, .table-hover or .table-active classes are added, the --bs-table-accent-bg is set to a semitransparent color to colorize the background. For each table variant, we generate a --bs-table-accent-bg color with the highest
  contrast depending on that color. For example, the accent color for .table-primary is darker while .table-dark has a lighter accent color.
```

Comment: Beyond this you are looking at doing SCSS/SASS and doing custom work on the generated CSS most likely.

Comment: This should work. I do not want the effect to be on all tables. I added this to a custom class and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
    <style>
        .table td:hover,
        .table th:hover {
            background-color: #313233 !important;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Type</th>
                <th scope="col">Column heading</th>
                <th scope="col">Column heading</th>
                <th scope="col">Column heading</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Default</th>
                <td>Column content</td>
                <td>Column content</td>
                <td>Column content</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="table-primary">
                <th scope="row">Primary</th>
                <td>Column content</td>
                <td>Column content</td>
                <td>Column content</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="table-dark">
                <th scope="row">Primary</th>
                <td>Column content</td>
                <td>Column content</td>
                <td>Column content</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Note: for your reference i have made hover effect for each cell you can change it to `tbody` for whole row.

Hope you get your answer..

Thanks...